# How to specify smt.string_solver=z3str3 through (Z3) API?

Tags: api, z3

I can run a (string) query with z3 from command line with or without specifying smt.string_solver=z3str3:

```
z3 [smt.string_solver=z3str3] input.smt
```

How can I **specify the same thing through API**?
I've tried printing the tactics names with:

```
/***************/
/* [0] Context */
/***************/
Z3_context ctx = mk_context();

/**************/
/* [1] Solver */
/**************/
Z3_solver solver = mk_solver(ctx);

/*******************************/
/* [2] Print the tactics names */
/*******************************/
for (i=0;i<Z3_get_num_tactics(ctx);i++)
{
    printf("tactic %d is %s\n",i,Z3_get_tactic_name(ctx,i));
}
```

And I get a list of **105 tactics names**, but **no z3str3** (sigh) ... I must be doing something wrong, what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z3str3` is not a tactic, but a parameter (for the default `smt` tactic). You can set it globally (ideally before constructing any contexts/solvers) by calling `Z3_global_param_set("smt.string_solver", "z3str3");`

Comment: Thanks, that works -- by the way, in the future will there only be one string solver? and z3str3 will be completely absorbed in z3? or not?